# Changing style in default EditText - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android. How can I get the normal Edit text with the orange border? 
As the default Edit text I am getting Edit texts with only lines (change to blue when in focus) without any border or background (Text will be displayed above these lines). I tried adding different styles to EditText by defining them in styles.xml. However, I could not get the normal Edit text with orange border. No Theme is defined for the application or the activity.
I am testing with an emulator in Platform 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orange border is not the "normal Edit text" style, but is a part of a specific theme, which is not present on every device. It was mainly used on old Android versions.

So you should not try to override the default style, it is generally a bad design and can confuse the users.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom drawable for the background. For example:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
```

Make sure that drawable is a nine-patch.